# how can I create a transparent circular QWebEngineView with an image border?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am currently trying to achieve a circular webview with a good looking border.
The content of the WebView (url) is not important it's all about having a circular webview with a border around it like

Border Image:

[image: Border Image]

The Window should be frameless so you see just a circular website with borders around it

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineProfile
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore          import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.resize(500,500)
        self.webview = QWebEngineView()
        self.useragent = QWebEngineProfile(self.webview)
        self.webview.setUrl(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/"))
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Panel)
        vbox = QGridLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.webview)
        frame.setLayout(vbox)
        radius = 200.0
        self.painterPath = QPainterPath()
        self.painterPath.addRoundedRect(QRectF(self.rect()), radius, radius)
        mask = QRegion(self.painterPath.toFillPolygon().toPolygon())
        self.webview.setMask(mask)
        self.setCentralWidget(frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[current view with above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quTiV.png)
That's the current code I have implemented and with that it's (almost) a circle but I didn't achieve adding an image/border around it.
after adding the border around the webview I want the frame to be completely transparent

That's what I try to achieve:

[image: target application]

Comment: you could add `imports` so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: you could also show what you get with current code - and explain what is wrong.

Comment: how about `QImage`, `QPixmap`, `drawImage`, `drawPixmap`

Comment: Sorry about that!
updated my post!

Answer (score 0):

I made it working by creating a second window and put it on top of it
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b5ss.png)